# Server 2003 VPN - Can only see server

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2003

I have a Server 2003 sitting behind a router at address 192.168.1.2, PPTP port is open and I am able to connect remotely via my Windows 7 client.  Routing and remote access is installed.  I have it set up to give ip range 192.168.1.20-192.168.1.29 to vpn clients.

However when I connect, I am given IP 192.168.1.20 and I am only able to see my server @ address 192.168.1.20.  How can I set it so that my VPN client PC uses the network just as a client sitting on any of my PCs local at the office do?  I imagine I need to set 192.168.1.1 as the default gateway but seeing that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the RRAS server for LAN routing.

Comment: Glad to help...